# Error importing application URL file ( Django 1.9 )

Tags: python, django

That's how the project `urls.py` file looks like :

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "controlPanel.views.post_home"),
    url(r'^posts/', include('controlPanel.urls')),
]
```

`controlPanel` app `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_home),
]
```

When i start the server, I receive an error

> The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: It seems that urls from app are not found, since the error message doesn't even contain the included URLconf name. Check if you point to the modules correctly.

Comment: Is the controlPanel app included in the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the INSTALLED_APPS. It is works whewn i used "import views", but when i try used "include" it is broke

Comment: In the shell, try `import controlPanel.urls` and `import <project_name>.urls`, to check whether either gives you an import error.

Comment: i do not have urls.pyc in my application folders

Comment: I can `import controlPanel.urls` but `import <project_name>.urls` receive an error: _Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings._

Comment: You may need to add your project name into the include. If your project is called `myproject`, try `url(r'^posts/', include('myproject.controlPanel.urls'))` in your main urls.py